# How to clear all the items from a PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a method that can clear the property grid of all its items? Or is there another way I can do this ?

Comment: you need to tell us the platform, and which property grid...asp.net? visual studio? WPF? winforms? silverlight?

Comment: Visual studio 2010, 3.5, winforms

Comment: "Clear" is rather ambiguous.  Set the SelectedObject property to null, for example.

Comment: is just setting it to null good coding practice though?

Comment: Using SelectedObject = null works to a certain extent. When the user clicks the load button to populate the grid again, it populates it in the state it was left before the form was closed. For example the categories that were expanded before are still expanded.

Comment: Try calling Dispose() on the Form and/or the PropertyGrid itself when the form is closed.

Answer (score 2):

If we can assume that the object you are using to populate the PropertyGrid has "clear" default values, the easiest thing to do is to just new up a new object to put there.

```
MyPropertyGrid.SelectedObject = new MyObject();
```

Comment: No, my object contains xml data. When a user clicks the x icon to close the form and then loads the form again, the same data is there from the previous session. I wish to clear the grid when the user clicks the x icon. The form containing the property grid is a child form, it belongs to a main application where you can create new sessions.

Comment: Years later, of course, but this advice really helped me. I was trying to set SelectedObject to null, but that didn't work. The property grid has no "clear" method, and even if you clear its dropdown combobox,  the grid itself can remain populated with properties and events. In my case, it wasn't enough to use **new MyObject()**; I instead had to set the property grid object's SelectedObject to **new Object()**. That worked: The resulting property grid then did not display any properties--it appeared to have been cleared. After, it was necessary to invoke **PropertyGridHost.Update()**.

Answer (score 0):

The way that worked for me is this:

```
MyPropertyGrid.SelectedObject = new Object();
MyPropertyGrid.Update();
```

Noticed that the property grid is set not to a custom object, but to an instance of the type System.Object. Code that needs to inspect the selected object can determine if the property grid is "empty" by testing whether `MyPropertyGrid.SelectedObjects` returns an array of one element and that `MyPropertyGrid.SelectedObjects[0].GetType() == typeof(System.Object)`.